# Is this site limited to discussions of electronic security?

Tags: discussion

Am I permitted to ask a question about paper records?

Or about physical security of other physical information?

---

[Update] Not ***just*** physical security (thanks for the link). Am I allowed to discuss encoding paper documents? Or social engineering?

is the site for all aspects of information security, or just electronic?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What about Physical Security?](http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/questions/311/what-about-physical-security)

Comment: There is already a lot of discussion about the site's scope, e.g.: http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/questions/464/regarding-our-scope-whats-acceptable-whats-not Ultimately, the worst that could happen to a well-phrased question would be that it gets migrated to another SE site.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This site is for all aspects of information security - this includes everything listed on [our FAQ](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> IT Security Stack Exchange is for Information Security professionals to discuss protecting assets from threats and vulnerabilities. Topics include, but are not limited to:
>
> - web app hardening
> - network security
> - social engineering, including phishing
> - risk management
> - policies
> - penetration testing
> - security tools
> - using cryptography
> - incident response
> - physically securing the office, datacentre, information assets etc.
>
> Questions on setting up your home PC antivirus may be more appropriate over at superuser.com; and questions on the deeper aspects of cryptography belong on crypto.SE.

So yes, please do ask about paper records.

Comment: Sorry that I Couldn't find the FAQ earlier. I am currently thinking "real world", so paper, social engineering and how to determine who to trust, how much and ow to verify trust. All of which sound like they will be on-topic.

Comment: Most useful information is under that help link at the top

Comment: I consistently failed to find that on every SO site I visit!  D'oh!

Comment: There is regular discussion about changing help to say FAQ instead... So it's not just you

Comment: Well,  any "old hand" would disdain "help", but make a beeline for "FAQ". I will seek out such a discussion and add my two Euro cents worth (about 2.11 US cents at today's rate)